# Issue with 'From' header when sending SMS via PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email, header, sms

I'm using PHP's mail() function to send SMS messages. It works fine, except that the message shows as coming from 'myuser@mr2.websitewelcome.com' when I want it to show as 'test@mydomain.com'. Here's the relevant code:

```
//Set headers and send mail.
$headers = "From: " . "test@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". "test@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";

mail( $from, '', $message, $headers );
```

I know this question has been asked before, but nothing has helped me so far. I've tried setting the header as '-f test@mydomain.com'. No luck.

Btw, if I send to an email address rather than a phone number, the headers work just fine.

Idk if this has anything to do with it, but my script gets called from an email forwarder that I set up in cpanel like:

```
Address                 Forward To
test@mydomain.com       |/home/myuser/public_html/handler.php
```

Also, here are the full headers of an email send to an email address:

```
Return-Path: <itch3@mr2.websitewelcome.com>
Received: from gateway01.websitewelcome.com (gateway01.websitewelcome.com [67.18.65.19])
    by mtain-mk01.r1000.mx.aol.com (Internet Inbound) with ESMTP id 1B28B3800008B
    for <myemail@me.com>; Wed,  8 Feb 2012 20:25:56 -0500 (EST)
Received: by gateway01.websitewelcome.com (Postfix, from userid 5007)
    id A69B35C21D4BD; Wed,  8 Feb 2012 19:25:55 -0600 (CST)
Received: from mr2.websitewelcome.com (mr2.websitewelcome.com [74.53.229.178])
    by gateway01.websitewelcome.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 9CBAF5C21D49D
    for <myemail@me.com>; Wed,  8 Feb 2012 19:25:55 -0600 (CST)
Received: from itch3 by mr2.websitewelcome.com with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <itch3@mr2.websitewelcome.com>)
    id 1RvIln-0003AQ-Cv
    for myemail@me.com; Wed, 08 Feb 2012 19:25:55 -0600
To: myemail@me.com
Subject: subject
From: "test@mydomain.com" <test@mydomain.com>
Reply-To: test@mydomain.com
Message-Id: <E1RvIln-0003AQ-Cv@mr2.websitewelcome.com>
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 19:25:55 -0600
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - mr2.websitewelcome.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - aol.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [2146 32003] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mr2.websitewelcome.com
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source: /usr/bin/php
X-Source-Args: /usr/bin/php -q /home/itch3/public_html/handler.php 
X-Source-Dir: switchon3.com:/public_html
X-Source-Sender: 
X-Source-Auth: itch3
X-Email-Count: 2
X-Source-Cap: aXRjaDM7Y3ZncnViYnM7bXIyLndlYnNpdGV3ZWxjb21lLmNvbQ==
x-aol-global-disposition: G
X-AOL-SCOLL-SCORE: 0:2:199012208:93952408  
X-AOL-SCOLL-URL_COUNT: 0  
x-aol-sid: 3039ac1d61854f3320a4018d
X-AOL-IP: 67.18.65.19
X-AOL-SPF: domain : mr2.websitewelcome.com SPF : none
```

Comment: I'm wandering, how do you send SMS via `mail()`?

Comment: @Vyktor: Most carriers map an email address to the cell phone number, e.g., Verizon uses `yournumber@vtext.com`.

Comment: Can you post the full headers (as received) for one of your normal (non-SMS) emails? We can take a look to see if anything is obviously invalid. (It may still be invalid, even if some mail clients understand what it should be).

Comment: @user617123 It needs to be the full headers. See this link for instructions on getting them in some of the major mail clients: http://wiki.pscs.co.uk/how_to%3Bobtaining_message_headers

Comment: @user617123 You might want to edit your last comment (and when you post full headers) to not show real email addresses (replace them with `address@example.com`, or similar). Otherwise, it increases the risk of receiving spam in the future.

Comment: @SimonMayer Full headers added to question. (I'll remove the real info later.)

Comment: @user617123 I can see something unusual, but I'm not sure if it's invalid. Can you try sending the message with a subject. What happens?

Comment: @SimonMayer Reposted the headers for message with a subject.

Comment: @user617123 If you set a subject, does the expected "From" address show? (tbh, that's a shot in the dark). I'm now fairly convinced that it's down to your Return-Path (that's the most likely situation). Does Return-Path change in the headers, if you run `mail( $from, '', $message, $headers, '-ftest@mydomain.com');` (note the lack of space after `-f`

Comment: @SimonMayer No, setting a subject doesn't fix the "From". But hey, the -f thing fixed it! Before I was using the -ftest@mydomain.com as the 4th argument of mail() not the fifth. Repost your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Return-Path to `test@mydomain.com`, like so:

```
mail( $from, '', $message, $headers, '-ftest@mydomain.com');
```

(note the lack of space after `-f`)

Answer (score 5):

Can you use the additional parameters argument to (again) declare the from address?

```
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message',
"From: webmaster@example.com\r\n", '-fwebmaster@example.com');
```

I generally add on the additional parameter when using mail() and it tends to fix most issues I've experienced.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $from is not set, so it defaults. Your code should be:

```
//Set headers and send mail.
$headers = "From: " . "test@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". "test@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";

$from = "test@mydomain.com";

mail( $from, '', $message, $headers );
```